# Save user generated form content as a PDF on server

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I have some report that is generated from a form. I need this form to be saved automatically on the server, on submitting. Is there any way to do it?

I tried researching on the subject, but Google just throws up links where the user gotta input the URL and press submit or such method. As this pdf should be generated and saved automatically after every form submission, I guess the preferable method would be to call a service or such to generate the PDF and then save it on the server. Can you plz give me a walk-through.Thanks in Advance.

I'm working in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pdf docs from php.net. It's all there for the taking. Good luck!
[PDF - Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)

Answer (score 0):

I am about to embark on the same journey as I need to create a script to turn a document into a .pdf file using PHP.  I don't know a lot about it yet, but it does seem possible.  Try this link for starters... 
http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/